# Dispatch plugin gives no output

Tags: plugin-dispatch

I am trying to use the Dispatch plugin to compile my latex code asynchronously.

Essentially, I am using the last code in the following question:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241430/vim-latex-suite-background-compilation

namely I type:

```
:Start! latexmk % <CR>
```

then essentially nothing happens, but in the command line I see written:

```
:!latexmk <path to the file>/file.tex (windows/?)
```

On the same file the command

```
:! latexmk % <CR>
```

produces the required output.

Any clues? I was under the impression that the code worked for half a day!

Answer (score 2):

The point of dispatch is to not clutter the screen when possible. The job is running in the background, most likely.

Use `:Copen` to open the quickfix window. It may not yet be populated. Check the dispatch docs.